# Visual Studio Plug-in to measure time spent on Solution/Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, plugins, project-management, project-planning

does anyone know of a Visual Studio (2008) Plug-in that attempts to track how long you've spent working on any given Solution or Project?

I realize this would be difficult, like at work I might leave a Solution open all day, but  only work on it for a couple of hours, on and off.

However at home, I might only open a Solution when I'm working on it.

Regardless, is there anything out there that at least attempts to track time spent? Do some/any Source Control reports achieve this?

This would be a resource for me to get a rough idea of how long I've spent on a bunch of projects.

cheers

Comment: I know! looks like there's no answer..? I might have to write my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any tools that can accomplish what you're looking for, I don't even think it would be accurate (if there were any). Still I would recommend [Hour Guard](http://www.nchsoftware.com/timesheet/index.html)  as a personal time measurement tool. It's free and very effective.

Comment: cool, seems to be pretty close to what I need. and its free! so why not.

Answer (score 5):

For personal time management you can consider [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com). It is external monitoring app that gathers statistics on what and for how long you do with your computer.

Not sure if it can distinguish different solutions open in the Visual Studio, but it can distinguish Office documents (although this functionality is only available for premium accounts).

Comment: cool, sounds like a great app....though seems like overkill....shame its not free. thanks for the help though +1

Comment: It is actually free, I have used it for years.

Comment: I also use time rescue, there is a free and paid version

Answer (score 5):

You can try my recently released [Visual Time Spent](http://www.svprogramming.net/visual-time-spent/index.html) add-in. It integrates with Visual Studio 2008/2010 and tracks time spent on solutions, projects and files. Idle time is detected as no activity for more than 2 minutes.