# How do I create a Visual Studio add in to analyze code

Tags: visual-studio, vsx

I want to have a go at writing add ins for visual studio that can play around with the code like resharper does e.g. look at a line of code and then suggest which "using statements" need to be added.

This is purely for educational purposes and a bit of fun, however I have no idea where to get started with the extensibility model. Can anyone point me in the right direction of some good resources

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855808/visual-studio-2008-plug-in-add-in-development-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with the [Common Compiler Infrastructure](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Peli/The-Common-Compiler-Infrastruture-goes-Open-Source/) if you are analyizing code compiled to MSIL.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the Roslyn CTP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx