# Visual Studio 2008 Break Point visible style

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, editor

Default settings makes each line where the break point is to be highlighted. Is there an option to make this line not to be highlighted (the point in the left side of the window is enough for me)

Thanks for help

Comment: The point only appears when you are debugging. How are you to know where you have set a break before you debug?

Comment: I dont understand what You mean. This point at the left side of the editor is there all the time (no matter if im debugging or not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can turn the breakpoint highlighting off - but you can go into tools/options/environment/fonts and colors and change the highlight color of breakpoint lines to be the same as your non-highlight default.

---

Looks like there *should* be a option for it, but it doesn't work (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/18/did-you-know-highlight-entire-source-line-for-breakpoints-and-current-statement-does-not-work-293.aspx). Doesn't seem fixed under 2010 either...

Comment: This works for me, but it sets the text to Black rather then not highlight it.

Comment: your link doesnt lead to a page anymore.

Comment: actually its been moved, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/18/did-you-know-how-to-highlight-the-entire-source-code-line-when-either-the-a-breakpoint-is-set-or-the-line-is-the-current-statement-293/

Comment: There is a Developer Community ticket to fix the debugger highlighting blocking syntax highlight problem. But it need upvotes, so please go upvote: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/breakpoint-highlight-c/736961

Maybe it will get fixed in a few more years.... :(

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create an addin for VS, which override the breakpoint style.

Comment: You have several tutorials on how to create VS Addin:
- MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w%28v=VS.90%29.aspx
- C# corner: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/addins11292005015631am/addins.aspx
- Albert Pascual: http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2009/01/27/how-to-create-a-addin-for-visual-studio-2008.aspx
 and some resources in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855808/visual-studio-2008-plug-in-add-in-development-getting-started
But I don't know how to override the breakpoint style.