# How long have I been working on a VS project?

Tags: visual-studio, time, statistics

Does Visual Studio has an option which can show me the time spent working on my project (probably, how long the project has been opened)? Or is there any other option which can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842524/visual-studio-plug-in-to-measure-time-spent-on-solution-project, but maybe there are newer solutions out there...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843328/an-add-on-to-keep-track-of-total-hours-worked-on-a-project-in-visual-studio

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212131/visual-studio-time-tracking-plugin

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Time Spent](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f19b73e4-c4ea-44d7-83ac-77f836b43aaa?SRC=Featured) seems to do exactly what you're asking for.

[image]

And then there is [CodeALike, a cloud service with Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4cd5e9ff-d183-46e0-9934-c8832924abb7) that shows not only  where you've been spending your time, but also what you've been doing. I can't find a sample image on their report per solution, but it's a feature of the product.
[image]